# Returning a Custom Map from a Query

Tags: apex, soql, query, map

Is it possible to return a custom map from a SOQL query?

I know we can do this:

```
Map<Id, Contact> contacts = new Map<Id, Contact>([SELECT Id ... FROM Contact]);
```

bus is it also possible to have something like this:

```
Map<String, Decimal> myMap = new Map<String, Decimal>(SELECT name, Amount__c FROM Cust_Obj);
```

I want the above map to be populated like this, without iterating through a list:

```
for(Cust_Obj CO : Cust_Obj_List) {
    myMap.put(CO.name, CO.Amount__c);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. You need to loop through for any mapping strategy besides by `Id`. The `for` loop is required to map by `Name`.

There are only three defined constructors on the [`Map Class`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm?search_text=map):

> #### `Map<T1,T2>()`
>
> Creates a new instance of the Map class. T1 is the data type of the keys and T2 is the data type of the values.
>
> **Signature**
>   `public Map<T1,T2>()`
>
> #### `Map<T1,T2>(mapToCopy)`
>
> Creates a new instance of the Map class and initializes it by copying the entries from the specified map. T1 is the data type of the keys and T2 is the data type of the values.
>
> **Signature**
>   `public Map<T1,T2>(Map<T1,T2> mapToCopy)`
>
> **Parameters**
>   *mapToCopy*
>   Type: `Map<T1, T2>`
>   The map to initialize this map with. T1 is the data type of the keys and T2 is the data type of the values. All map keys and values are copied to this map.
>
> #### `Map<ID,sObject>(recordList)`
>
> Creates a new instance of the Map class and populates it with the passed-in list of sObject records. The keys are populated with the sObject IDs and the values are the sObjects.
>
> **Signature**
>   `public Map<ID,sObject>(List<sObject> recordList)`
>
> **Parameters**
>   *recordList*
>   Type: `List<sObject>`
>   The list of sObjects to populate the map with.

There's also the `putAll` method but it gives you the same result:

> #### `putAll(sobjectArray)`
>
> Adds the list of sObject records to a map declared as Map or Map.
>
> **Signature**
>   `public Void putAll(sObject[] sobjectArray)`
>
> **Parameters**
>   *sobjectArray*
>   Type: `sObject[]`
>
> **Return Value**
>   Type: Void
>
> **Usage**
>   This method is similar to calling the Map constructor with the same input.

Comment: is there a more efficient way of creating such a map?

Comment: @ashkanent The `for` loop you have in your OP is the most efficient it gets for a map of that nature.